# How to hide url inside a .lib file in objective C/Xcode/iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I want to make an ad framework for iOS, so i need to to hide the  url of 'requested server' inside the lib file. But as there are several tools present like otool, to decompile lib file so i am afraid hacker can decompile  our lib file and get the url and send continuos ad request. So can anyone please give me some idea to how to keep our 'URL' safe from hacker. Thanks.

Comment: The URL is (1) presented to the operating system, and (2) easily captured by the router. Hiding it in the source code won't do you any good.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bad idea... if you need to implement protection or rate-limiting then do it server-side. Not by playing hide-and-seek in client code.

Comment: But how to do it if hackers disguise themselves as a real persion and send request same way as sdk does and get impression. So in this case server side won't be able to detect it???

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to protect against?

Comment: I am trying to make sure that hacker can't request ad continuosly and those not get impression and not spoil our clients money (since they are requesting ad but don't provide a chance to display it, so spoil the impression).

Comment: Your server code will need to recognize this behavior and defend against it.

Comment: So, add server-side support to only return one "ad" every, say, 30 seconds to a particular client. And ask yourself "why would a 'hacker' do this? How does he benefit financially from this behavior?" Because, frankly, if your ad platform is *so* popular that hackers are requesting dozens of ads per second, you have other problems to worry about.

Comment: Hacker will do so because he is getting impression and earning money for that impression. And if he changes his id after few request will server have any chance to detect it???

Comment: If you are paying people money simply because they connect to your server and receive some data then "hiding" your strings won't help. The problem is your design.